# Deploy a Sponsor Contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I'm trying to deploy a sponsor_contract that will pay transactions fee for Wallet A, to claim token and transfer it to other wallet.

Here is my code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract SponsorContract {
    address public sponsor;
    address public sponsoredParty;
    uint public sponsorshipAmount;
    bool public isApproved;
    
    constructor(address _sponsor, address _sponsoredParty, uint _sponsorshipAmount) {
        sponsor = _sponsor;
        sponsoredParty = _sponsoredParty;
        sponsorshipAmount = _sponsorshipAmount;
        isApproved = false;
    }
    
    function approveSponsorship() public {
        require(msg.sender == sponsoredParty, "Only the sponsored party can approve the sponsorship.");
        isApproved = true;
    }
    
    function cancelSponsorship() public {
        require(msg.sender == sponsor, "Only the sponsor can cancel the sponsorship.");
        require(!isApproved, "The sponsorship has already been approved and cannot be cancelled.");
        selfdestruct(payable(sponsor));
    }
    
    function withdrawFunds() public {
        require(msg.sender == sponsoredParty, "Only the sponsored party can withdraw funds.");
        require(isApproved, "The sponsorship has not been approved yet.");
        payable(sponsoredParty).transfer(sponsorshipAmount);
    }
}
```

And this is the error when I deploy:

`creation of SponsorContract errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid address (argument="address", value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=address/5.5.0) (argument=null, value="", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)`

Can you give me a hand. Many thanks <3

Comment: would you share the method that you tried to deploy the contract?
it seems you didn't provide the constructor args when you deploy.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `constructor` has 3 parameters, you need to pass them when you deploy the contract. If you do not pass, you get that error. since you are on remix ide, next to `deploy` you have an input area to pass correct arguments.

[image]